# What does $99x^2+99y^2+2xy-100x-100y-2400=0$ represent?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to figure out what $$99x^2+2xy+99y^2-100x-100y-2400=0$$

represents? I first tried to get the idea from drawing it in Matlab and looking at the figure it looks like a circle with center $(\frac{50}{99},\frac{50}{99})$. But then I tried to rotate the axes by $45$ degree to get rid of the $xy$ term. I got the following equation $$100X^2+98Y^2-100\sqrt{2}X-2400=0$$
which is an ellipse. That means the equation is represents an ellipse with center $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$ with respect to $X$-axis and $Y$-axis which are the original $x$-axis and $y$-axis rotated by $45$ degree. Could any help me with which one is the correct one?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Identifying_rotated_conic_sections

Answer (score 2):

Your transformation is right, and you obtained the correct expression. The given equation represents an ellipse.

You could easily classify the given expression as one of the conic sections by computing the discriminant. In particular, by comparing the given expression with $A x^2 + B xy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F=0$, we get 
$$B^2 -4 A C <0.$$

Had the given equation corresponded to a circle, then $B=0$ and $A = C$. In this case, $B \neq 0$, but $B^2-4AC<0$. Therefore, the given equation is that of a rotated ellipse.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant for more information.

Comment: maybe you could incorporate the basic message of the referenced page into your answer

Comment: @Math Lover In the referenced page I did not get any information regarding $B\neq 0$. Also could you please point out what did I do wrong in transforming the expression? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mint The given equation represents an ellipse with foci $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Your transformation is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

That there's an ellipse. If there's any $xy$ term, it can't be a circle. However, its eccentricity is only
$\frac1{5\sqrt2}$, so it looks a lot like a circle.

Comment: check the other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417246/11206)